# Website freeze - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I got an issue with the website under the address http://mawek3.pro-linuxpl.com/custom-paintball-jerseys-hyper-pro.php

The problem appears when I click on the website logo in the left top corner, it navigates me to the homepage. Than  "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" error is showing, website freeze, sliders stop working.

I've tried to remove lots of code, but I can find any problem. Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is with XMLHttpRequests setting asynch flag false - or perhaps it's jquery with asynch false ... either way, it's a long road to change from synchronous XHR to asynchronous XHR - the deprecation warning has existed in modern browsers for a number of years, how have you not noticed?

Comment: Well , the website stops responding in the "upper part" around the slider and navigation. I've checked the console and it's the only warning. When there is no warning, the website works just fine.  So You suggesting that this warning not cause the problems?

Comment: yes, but that warning shows why you get the freezing, because a request that is synchronous freezes the UI until the request is completed ( a big download will be horrendous!! but even a slow response will be annoying) ... you'll need to find all `xmlhttprequest` (or jquery `$.ajax` `$.get` `$.put` `$.load` etc etc) and make sure they don't do think synchronously

Comment: Any idea how to do it? Basically its nothing custom, just bootstrap and the jquery. I've tried to switch off all the other js scripts and leaved just jquery and bootstrap

Comment: I thought my comment was self explanatory

Comment: Iam kind of newbie, always using bootstrap for fast prototyping / small websties, so i didnt dive into much... anyway thanks!